# Best practices for organizing your Redis data structure in the code

Tags: python, redis

So I'm moving from PostgreSQL to Redis as main database in my project to get the best performance. Now my code contains a lot of HSET, HMSET, HGET, SADD, SREM, SINTER, SORT and other calls to Redis spread everywhere throughout the code. We don't have any ORM with Redis nor any data model description. While I have the structure of my data in my mind, it's not a big problem for me to maintain this code. But once another dev needs to work with it, or even me after just a year, it will become a huge pain to get it all together and be sure you don't miss anything.

Thus my question. What are the best practices for organizing the data-storage code without ORMs and proper data models? I see a lot of articles on how to call Redis here and there to store data in it, but no recommendations whatsoever on how to do it without making your code a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using rom: https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom

It allowed me to describe models clearly and use active record to work with them. Takes care of indexes and stuff under the hood, quite simple to use and nice